# Finding mode and median of a file with Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mode, median

I was having trouble with this section of my code on a project and have tried doing mode and median in multiple ways but all have been unsuccessful.  However, I do need to use dictionaries in the mode part so any advice there would be extremely helpful.

```
    # Find median
    order = converted_numbers.sort()
    middle = count/2
    if middle % 2 == 0:
        median = (converted_numbers[middle - 1] + converted_numbers[middle]) / 2
    else:
        median = converted_numbers[middle]

    # Mode calculations
    number_counts = {}
    mode = 0
    freq = 0
    for i in converted_numbers:
        if i in number_counts:
            number_counts[i] += 1
        else:
            number_counts[i] = 1
    for i in number_counts:
        counts = int(number_counts[i])
        mode = max(counts)
```

Comment: which version of python are you using? 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using version 3 and if you need to see the rest of my code I'd be happy to provide it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- `list.sort()` doesn't return a value. So, if you want to have a sorted list (separate from the original).

  ```
  ordered_numbers = converted_numbers[:] # copy it
  ordered_numbers.sort()
  ```
- Use floor division, and check if `count` is even, not `middle`:

  ```
  middle = count // 2
  if count % 2 == 0:
      median = (ordered_numbers[middle - 1] + converted_numbers[middle]) / 2
  else:
      median = ordered_numbers[middle]
  ```
- To compute the mode, you can use one of python's core libraries, the `collections` library, and just quickly get it:

  ```
  from collections import Counter

  counter = Counter(ordered_numbers) # no need to be sorted
  mode    = counter.most_common(1)   # returns the most commonly occuring item
  ```

EDIT:

Since the requirement is to use a dictionary, we can simply write it as follows:

```
number_counts = {}
for num in ordered_numbers:
    if number_counts.get(num, None):
        number_counts[num] = 1
    else:
        number_counts[num] += 1

mode = ordered_numbers[0] # set to a number already in list
mode_freq = 0
for num, freq in number_counts.items():
    if freq > mode_freq:
        mode, mode_freq = num, freq
```

In place of a regular `dict`, you can use a `defaultdict`, which allows you to not need if an element is present

```
from collections import defaultdict

number_counts = defaultdict(int)
for num in ordered_numbers:
    number_counts[num] += 1

mode = #.... same as above
```

Comment: thanks so much! however for the mode I do have to use dictionaries, which is what I was trying to do and was wondering if you had any advice for doing it that way specifically?

Comment: and to be specific I keep getting this error message line 56, in <module>
    mode = max(counts)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable